# AC/AC power supply for PCB

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, pcb-assembly, iec

I am trying to source the right setup for powering this PCB:

[image]

I have found an 18 V AC/AC power supply but it has a barrel connector:

[image]

I am struggling to work out how to connect the barrel connector to the three-pin slot on the PCB. I have found a barrel connector to 2-pin screw terminal but I'm unsure if this would work:

[image]

It looks like the PCB wants a connection to an IEC panel mount, but I can't find a 15 V or 18 V AC/AC power supply that has an IEC connector.

Comment: Do you need *both* the +12 V and -12 V rails? If so, then you would need a 15-0-15 V centre-tapped transformer (or a transformer with two 15 V secondaries wired appropriately). Do you have a link to the source of the PCB? Also, what are you going to use it for, in case somewhere here has any good ideas.

Comment: There are many sizes of barrel connectors. They are ususally specified by 2 numbers outer diameter and pin diameter, units are millimeters. Example: 5.5/3.5. But, @AndrewMorton is correct, you need a center tapped transformer. A half wave rectifier would only need plain 18V, but that would only be for low current applications.

Comment: The figure on the PCB for the power input is indicating the use of a PCB screw terminal block—[example](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/670/tb003v_500-2306810.pdf).

Comment: Is this a permanent solution. You could supply it with a AC voltage from a wall wart to an onboard transformer that will turn that into two AC phases. You could go with DC and use Converters, one for + and one for -. You need to be sure they can be configured the way you want, not all will work. If ground passes through probably not.

Comment: The module you're trying to power is not a very good power supply, just so you know. The 7812 and 7912 are linear regulators, which are pretty inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick comments, appreciate it. @AndrewMorton, the source is https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/174985875588?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=F6oCWlbbQvm&sssrc=2349624&ssuid=6MwlhjRxSbe&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY. Thank you Mattman944 and Gil. Hearth, I think your right. I got this as it was cheap and I wanted to start cheap but it looks like I should have done more research.  I will look up the centre tapped transformer thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Steven_25 Do you actually need Eurorack-compatible items or is it just the power supply for ~something~ that you want?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, it was to power a euro rack I was beginning. The maker replied to my email asking for more info and he said I can use a 18v Ac/Ac power supply with a barrel connector. This then goes to a dc barrel Jack, and then I wire positive to both the +12 and -12 and then do the ground. I did find an 18v ac/ac adapter so hopefully this is the solution. He went on to say that when he originally built the pcb, there was a few ac/ac 15v adapters on the market but have now gone. Hopefully this will work. Thanks for thinking of me!